# Converting dwg file into gltf with color

Tags: autodesk-forge, gltf

I have an Autocad dwg file that i want to convert into gltf. I have used autodesk forge as well as autodesk forge tools in VS Code to get gltf. Both the tools are able to  convert into gltf but the problem is there is no color in the gltf, it is just black and white. 
Is there some way to get color in the gltf file or obj file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping of colors from Forge models to glTF in [forge-convert-utils](https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-convert-utils) is pretty basic at the moment but it should be able to get at least some basic diffuse color. Try this:

- open the gltf file, find the list of `materials`, and see what colors you see in `baseColorFactor` properties; if the values are `[0,0,0,0]`, the problem is in the conversion
- if you see non-zero values there, perhaps there's a problem with lighting up the model in your viewing application; for example, when loading a glTF model into a three.js app, you must add at least an ambient light otherwise the model will remain black

If you're still having issues, please consider sharing your DWG (confidentially) with us via `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com`, and we'll debug it locally.

EDIT: As discussed in https://github.com/petrbroz/vscode-forge-tools/issues/16, the issue was a lack of support for meshes with *vertex colors* in the converter library. As of [forge-convert-utils](https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-convert-utils) version 3.4.0, and [vscode-forge-tools](https://github.com/petrbroz/vscode-forge-tools) version 1.5.1, vertex colors in Forge models are now properly translated into glTF vertex colors.

Comment: i have created a simple cube in AutoCAD and applied color. Now when I preview it using Autodesk Forge Tools - 3D view in vs code, it is showing the color but when i download it in gltf format and view it using some gltf viewer like https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/ , it shows diffused grayish kind of model. No color is shown there.

Comment: And when you preview the cube using Forge Viewer, is it colored?

Comment: Thank You so much @petr-broz for this fix.